# segmentation fault in linked list implementation

Tags: gcc, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Following code gives segmentation fault in gcc compiler.
Earlier it was working fine but not working after updating my compiler.
don't know what's happening its working in some online compilers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

//push function to add node at the beginning
void push(struct node** head,int data){
    //creating new node
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    //pointing to head if not null
    if((*head) != NULL)
        newNode->next = (*head);

    //making new node as head
    (*head) = newNode;

}

//fuction to display linked list
void display(struct node* head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",head->data);
        head=head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    struct node* head;
    push(&head,20);
    push(&head,10);
    push(&head,5);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside push function you have check for head against NULL, but when you are passing head from main you have not initialized it to NULL.

```
struct node* head;
```

should be modified as

```
struct node* head = NULL;
```

Comment: Still its showing segmentation fault after intializing head with null

Comment: Its not crashing on Ubuntu once i Initialize head to NULL. Can you please run you program with gdb and once it crashes send output of backtrace command ..